# Vim backspace key only works on new text

Tags: vim

For fun I decided to compile vim from source. Long story short the build seemed to go fine, but when I enter insert mode I cannot use the <BACKSPACE> key to delete existing characters or newlines created using the <ENTER> key in insert mode. The distro's pre-built package does this just fine. I also know there's no problem with the backspace key itself because I can backspace over characters I've just typed, just not existing characters.

It almost makes sense, as vim operates on a per-line basis most of the time. Is there a flag I need to set in order to support this behavior? Or is it faster by design to enter normal mode to delete existing characters/newlines?

Comment: Check your .vimrc file. You can copy the one from the pre-built package. Alternatively use `dd` to delete lines, `J` to join them, `o` and `O` to add new ones.

Comment: "backspace over characters I've just typed, just not existing characters" -- what does that even mean? It seems like the backspace is not the problem here.

Comment: @maksymko If you type ":set backspace=" into vim you'll see what I tried to describe. I'll admit I'm not the best with words at times :-)

Comment: @Joe you described what I'm seeing perfectly, I can delete what I just typed, but not what was already there

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wow, second time I've figured out the answer minutes after posting the question.

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Must have been set automatically by the distro's package vimrc. Hope this answer helps someone else! For more info:

```
:help i_backspacing
```

Comment: Hmm, after reading that manual, I thought that removing that "start" setting from my setting can be an interesting idea :)